# Optional parameters in Excel JS custom functions?

Tags: office-js

I was trying to implement an optional parameter in an Excel JS custom function earlier but was getting a "#VALUE" error. I'm almost certain that this is because I don't have the parameter set to be optional in the customfunctions.json metadata.

Here are the parameters in my custom functions metadata:

```
"parameters": [
      {
          "name": "Indicator",
          "description": "Indicator ID",
          "type": "string",
          "dimensionality": "scalar"
      },
      {
          "name": "Date",
          "description": "Date",
          "type": "string",
          "dimensionality": "scalar"
      }
  ],
```

and I set the date parameter to be optional in the function like so:

```
function getData(indicator, date, handler) {
   // Default value for date is 'latest'
   if (typeof date === 'undefined') { date = 'latest'; }
   ....
```

Please note that "Date" in the json metadata becomes "date" in the actual JS function.

So my question is how would I make a parameter optional in the json metadata? Is this a feature of custom functions yet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional parameters are now supported. You simply add “optional”:true to each parameter. It is described in the custom functions metadata topic at https://aka.ms/customfunctions

Comment: Thanks again, Keyur!!